# Row have title centered but other widget on the right

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'd like to keep my title **centered** **& on 1 `maxLine`** for **any screen size** while keeping my `IconButton` on the **far right** :

[image: title needs to stay centered image]

*So far this is what I've written but* it does not adapt to different screen sizes *(title doesn't stay centered)* :

[image: title doesn't stay centered image]

Keep in mind `title length` can vary slightly depending on `state`

**FULL CODE :**

```dart
Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(40),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
          ),
          child: BottomAppBar(
              elevation: 4,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const TitleRowQuestion(),
                  ],
                ),
              ))),
    );
```

```dart
class TitleRowQuestion extends StatelessWidget {
  const TitleRowQuestion({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: SizedBox(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 4,
          child: Text(
            'Title stay centered one line'.hardcoded,
            maxLines: 1,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: IconButton(
                splashRadius: 20,
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.help_outline,
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this on  appBar title?

Comment: I'm doing this inside a bottomAppBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this widget,

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(23),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(24, 0), //24 for icon size
          child: Text(
            'Title needs to stay centered',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: IconButton(
          splashRadius: 20,
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.help_outline,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: this doesn't work as it puts my text on two lines :/ I've added more code to my question

Comment: Yes on small screen it split into two line. let me check the update one

Comment: check update one. you might find better instead of translating icon size

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
 Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '  datasdgasdgksagdkasgdk',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ))),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Text('data2'),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
```

This Works on all Screen Size for me, Hope this helps you too..

Comment: Yes thank you  I've thought of this one, it could work but not ideal as text could overlap button on very small screen : /

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `ListTile`, and make the the Title of it as Row with MainAxis centered, and the trailing would be your Icon:

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(23),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Something"),
          ],
        ),

        trailing: IconButton(
          splashRadius: 20,
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.help_outline,
          ),
        ),
      )
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately title isn't exactly centered relative to screen with this approach

Comment: that's because of the padding you are using. IconButton already taking space from right.

Comment: So I should add left padding to Text to center it ?

Comment: If text is too long it overflows

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

first remove the padding widget in the scaffold,

and use two containers with height and width depending on the media query context.

```
Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      ),
      child: BottomAppBar(
          elevation: 4,
          //remove padding widget
          //if there are many column children, use SingleChildScrollView
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                TitleRowQuestion(),
              ],
            ),
          ))),
);
```

this is your bottomAppBar:

```
return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [// use two containers and give them height and width depending on the media query context
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 4, left: 8),
          color: Colors. blue,
          child: const Center(
            //SingleChildScrollView with scrollDirection in horizontal for long string
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Text(
                'Title stay centered one line',
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4),
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: IconButton(
            splashRadius: 20,
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.help_outline,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```