# title widget to be centered and icon widgets at the right side in one row

Tags: flutter, dart

the question is exactly same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73247684/row-have-title-centered-but-other-widget-on-the-right)

but I did not find an answer from the post.

my goal is to set the title widget in the center 
[image]

and other two buttons on the right side.
the solutions in the link all put the title widget slightly on the left side.

does anyone know how to do this without using Stack? I'm afraid of the title widget being over the button widgets when the title gets too long.

the code:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Row(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(width: 17),
        Text(
          'TITLE',
          style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Row(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){null;},
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Icon(Icons.wallet_membership, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 17),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){Get.toNamed('/wallet_setting');},
                child: const SizedBox(
                  child: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ]
        )

      ]
  ),
)
```

Comment: Can you include your current snippet ?

Comment: code or screenshot of the current status? I just need a proper structure to make it work. I also didn't include the code because it doesn't work anyway

Comment: We need [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: are you using it on column ?

Comment: yes it's on Column widget

Comment: Ok let me give you a better way, want some animation ?

Comment: does it matter whether it's on column or not? what is the structure like?

Comment: Yes it matters, there are some different types of widgets

Comment: is that edited answer with stack what you wanted to try? I didn't want to use stack as the would be overlaying on the buttons once the title gets too long

Comment: does your two button fixed ?

Comment: technically yes but I wanted something that works relatively, even if the buttons are more than two and so on

Comment: Did you follow that answer on your attached like ? I cant see anything on current snippet

Comment: Does [Row have title centered but other widget on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73247684/10157127) answer your question

Comment: using flex? I think that's the same as the answer that used Opacity, but your reference should work correctly. 

I just saw the answer - the one with Align doesn't work, but with flex it should work. I must try

Comment: Opacity and flex isn't the same.  Check *Another way* part

Comment: I meant they are same in the way that they both put same space in the left and right side of the text so the text can be centered

I just tried the method with flex and sadly it gave me overflow. I tried to remove flex of the center widget but it made the text in two line. this can't be a good solution as the length of the title can't be really flexible

Comment: I prefer my title to be sort and simple, It depends on how you do.   You can include full sample widget that will reproduce the issue, others may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `centerTitle:true` on `Appbar`

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  title: Text("title"),
  actions: [
```

---

Another way

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.purple,
  height: 40 * 2,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_before)),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: SizedBox(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Text(
              'TITLE',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Icon(Icons.wallet_membership,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 17),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: const SizedBox(
                        child:
                            Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

---

**Preferable solution:**
You can `implements PreferredSizeWidget` to create custom Appbar. Play with color and other decoration.

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Text("title"),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                //you can use callback method to get onpressed
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight * 2);
}
```

And use like `appBar: MyAppBar(),`

Comment: that is not an appbar area. the appbar stays above the widget(the row with an arrow)
and the widget with the issue is the one below with the letter 'title'

Comment: you can use  `bottom` on   `appBar: AppBar(bottom: AppBar(`.  It will easier if you include your current code, better `implements PreferredSizeWidget`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

first make widget from your right widgets:

```
Widget _rightIcons() {
    return Row(children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          null;
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Icon(Icons.wallet_membership, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 17),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
           Get.toNamed('/wallet_setting');
        },
        child: const SizedBox(
          child: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

then build your header like this:

```
Row(
    children: [
      _rightIcons(),
      Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'TITLE',
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Opacity(
        opacity: 0,
        child: _rightIcons(),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: @dfassf was it what you want?

Comment: the trick here is set same exact widgets on right to the left on make them invisible, this way you have your title center.

Comment: I actually thought of it too, it's like a trick so I wanted to know if there is any other way to solve without using a 'trick'

Answer (score 0):

Try this One

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'TITLE',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        )
      )
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){null;},
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Icon(Icons.wallet_membership, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 17),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){Get.toNamed('/wallet_setting');},
            child: const SizedBox(
              child: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ]
      )
    )
  ],
)
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: I already tried this one, if you look at it carefully the title is in the middle of the width excluding the buttons. not exactly in the middle of the whole device screen width

Answer (score 0):

i think you should wrap it with centre

Comment: yes it would make it centered but in a wrong position

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).